# How to give a File name automatically when Saving a image

Tags: android

When I save the image to the sdcard it automatically saves it with the given file name. If a file with the same name already exist, it is replaced.

I want to store the images with file names in a sequence where if the file `Image` exists it will be saved  with `image1` next `image2` and so on.

Please advise how to do that, as I am new to programming.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way would be to save what the last ID was in Shared prefs..

Comment: you can try to use the MD5 Hash. or try the date and time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File fileDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File[] images = fileDir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
    public boolean accept(File file, String name){
        if(name,toLowerCase().startsWith("image"));
        return true;
        else return false;
    }});

File fileToSave;

if(images.length > 0)
fileToSave = new File(fileDir.getAbsolutePath(), "image" + images.length);
else
fileToSave = new File(fileDir.getAbsolutePath(), "image");
```

something like that'll do.

Answer (score 1):

you must do two things
1. check is there file with same name 
2. change name of the file you want to save

1. It's simple I think , you can also try to open this file named e.g. "name" , if it opens, change the "name" to "name1" and try it again.
2. you must keep variable named `string` e.g. `String newName` , than 
   `String newName = "name" + 1` , something like this

Regards Hayk Nahapetyan

Answer (score -1):

Cut and paste the image you want to name from the SD card to the internal storage. After renaming, copy the images to SD card or use  it as  a backup.